# force a page to https and then any others back again

Tags: php, redirect

php which i need to always be secure, so i found this:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') { header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); exit(); }?>
```

which redirects the page to use https.

but when they browse to y.php from that secure page i need the to go back to http.

i have used:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80') { header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); exit(); }?>
```

---

Edit ill explain a liitle more sorry.

I have a wordpress site that i need 1 page forced to use HTTPS and all other not to use HTTPs at all.

the page itself is called /help and the wordpress installation uses permalinks.

if the user was to browse to any other page on HTTPs eg /hello it needs to force them back to http

hope this helps

Comment: Don't check by port, use $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'

Comment: I don't think I am understanding your question.

Comment: basically when the user lands on form.php it will force them to https. but should they then browse to any other content page on the site it needs to revert back to http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what your asking, this will make sure the /help is alway https and that every other path is under http protocal

**PHP**

```
$request = strtolower(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

if (0 === strpos($request, '/help')) { // liberal matches
//if (preg_match('/^\/help\/?$', $request)) { //conservative
        if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') {
            header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
        }
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
        header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit;
    }
```

**.htaccess** *(with mod_rewrite enabled)*

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/help\/? #liberal matches /help /helped /helper
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/help\/?$ #conservative matches /help and /help/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/help      #liberal matches /help /helped /helper
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/help\/?$ #conservative matches /help and /help/
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Perferct, that works a treat and also with worpdress permalinks. I have hadded this to my header include and works as intended. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Use the function below to check if the current page is SSL, it's used in a widely popular community php library:

```
/**
 * Check if the current page is SSL
 */
function securepages_is_secure() {
  return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

And then redirect your user when the page doesn't have a form and securepages_is_secure() returns TRUE.

Comment: see comment above sorry if my explanation was not clear enough

Comment: The function above will work for that case. Redirect your user when the page doesn't have a form (check if page isn't form.php) and securepages_is_secure() returns TRUE.

Comment: sorry the page i need secure does not have a form on it, the above was an example -- explained a litte more in the main post sorry

Answer (score 0):

Does this htaccess solution help:

```
<Location /form.php>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this broke the site :(, ps this is a WP site with permalinks turned on